# Dependency issues running "cabal test" for Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, hunit

I'm running my first "cabal test" for Haskell, but I get the error:

```
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring sample-0.1.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
base ==4.7.*
```

sampel.cabal:

```
-- Initial sample.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                sample
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable SampleTest
  main-is:             SampleTest.hs
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && <4.8, HUnit >=1.2 && <1.3
  hs-source-dirs:      test, src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of GHC are you using? And how did you install Haskell?

Comment: GHC version 7.10.2, I installed the windows file from here https://www.haskell.org/downloads.  I installed the "Haskell Platform" version.

Comment: I changed the line " base >= 4.7 && <4.8" to " base >= 4.8 && <4.9" and I works okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions of GHC come bundled with versions of base.  GHC 7.10.2 uses base 4.8.1.0.

Your cabal must be using a slightly out of date template....

You should either change the range of acceptable base version (as you did in your comment above), or use a different version of GHC.